# Why exponentpush token is null

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, push-notification

why ExponentPush Token is null  I console.log token it show null
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

**See image below:**

[image]

push_notifications.js

```js
import {Permissions, Notifications} from 'expo';
import axios from 'axios';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

const PUSH_ENDPOINT = 'http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/tokens';
export default async () => {
    let previousToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('pushtoken');
    console.log(previousToken);
    if (previousToken) {
        return;
    } else {
        let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        if (status !== 'granted') {
            return;
        }
        let token = await Expo.Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
        await  axios.post(PUSH_ENDPOINT, {token: {token}});
        AsyncStorage.setItem('pushtoken', token);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let previousToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('pushtoken');
console.log(previousToken);
```

You are trying to access `AsyncStorage` to find the item with key `pushtoken`. If this app is running for the first time, it will be `null`. You need to perform `setItem` at least once.